# How can I get more error message about `HIVE_BAD_DATA` in AWS Athena?

Tags: hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am running `select ***` statement in `Athena` against a database table in `glue`. I get this error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value 'false' for field 38: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

This query ran against the "video" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 6ab2d2e8-c0a0-4329-ac91-be2683c05462.
```

From the error message, I understand it is about a field type of `boolean` which its value is a string `'false'`. But it doesn't tell me which column has such error. I have a table which includes more than 30 columns and about 9 of them are boolean. Is there an easier way for me to find out the problem column instead of just querying each of them one by one?

Comment: I think it's saying that the 38th column of some row is expecting a number, but it contained `false`. You can try creating a smaller test file (eg 5 lines) and see if it works correctly. That will tell you if the table definition is wrong, or if a particular line is wrong.